# Clicking through a list of elements with puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, puppeteer

I am wanting to use puppeteer to scrape job data off of ZipRecruiter for a personal project of mine. My current method is to use puppeteer to go to a ziprecruiter URL such as `https://www.ziprecruiter.com/candidate/search?search=React&location=San+Francisco` and grab all of the job names that are clickable. Due to these items not actually being `<a>` tags, I cannot simply grab the href attribute of them and use puppeteer to go to that page and then pass of the page's HTML to cheerio to scrape the data I need.

Instead, I am trying to save all the job titles (class is `('.just_job_title')`) in a variable, and then use puppeteer to click through each job title, opening the new page, and if this page belongs to ZipRecruiter, scrape the information I need. Then use `page.goBack()` to return to the original URL. However, my current method is causing an error: `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Protocol error (Runtime.callFunctionOn): Target closed.` and I am not quite sure how I can achieve the desired scenario I outline above.

Here is my code:

```
export async function getJobsZipRecruiter(params) {
const ZIPRECRUITER_URL = `https://www.ziprecruiter.com/candidate/search?search=React&location=San+Francisco`;

try {
  console.log('Trying to scrape *************');
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto(ZIPRECRUITER_URL);
  await page.waitForSelector('#createAlertPop');

 
  const jobs = await page.$$('.just_job_title');

  jobs.forEach(async (job) => {
      await page.waitForSelector('.just_job_title');
      await job.click();
      console.log('Yes it worked');
      // Get the data you want here and push it into the data array
      await page.goBack();
    });

  console.log(jobs)


  await browser.close();
  return zipRecruiterJobs;
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err);
}


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `.forEach()` does not suit well for async tasks: it starts all the callbacs at once, so in your case all the functions are mixed and work with one page messing thigs up. Usually for..of loop is better.
2. `'.just_job_title'` element is a child of a link, so you can collect all the hrefs and process them one by one.

Try something like this:

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

async function getJobsZipRecruiter(params) {
  const ZIPRECRUITER_URL = `https://www.ziprecruiter.com/candidate/search?search=React&location=San+Francisco`;

  try {
    console.log('Trying to scrape *************');
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
    const [page] = await browser.pages();
    await page.goto(ZIPRECRUITER_URL);
    await page.waitForSelector('#createAlertPop');

    const urls = await page.evaluate(() => Array.from(
      document.querySelectorAll('a[href][data-tracking="job_title"].job_link.t_job_link'),
      link => link.href,
    ));

    console.log(urls);
    const zipRecruiterJobs = [];

    for (const url of urls) {
      await page.goto(url);
      if (!page.url().startsWith('https://www.ziprecruiter.com/')) continue;
      await page.waitForSelector('h1.job_title');
      // Get the data you want here and push it into the data array
      zipRecruiterJobs.push(
        await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector('h1.job_title').innerText)
      );
    }

    await browser.close();
    console.log(zipRecruiterJobs);
    return zipRecruiterJobs;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}

getJobsZipRecruiter();
```